# Simple parameterized select query takes time to execute in C#

Tags: c#, sql, ssms

I have a table structure like below :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MainTbl](
[RowNum] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[TxtID] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
[TxtKey] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
[TrnDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[SrcID] [varchar](20) NOT NULL DEFAULT (''),
[ElemName] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
[TblXml] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
[ActiveStatus] [varchar](20) NOT NULL DEFAULT (''),
[DevLvl] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
[Archive] [bit] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_MainTbl_Archive]  DEFAULT ((0)),

CONSTRAINT [pkMainTbl] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
([RowNum] ASC)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

and executing below query to fetch xml :

```
select TblXml from MainTbl with (nolock) 
where TrnDate < @TrnDate and TxtID = @TxtID and TxtKey = @TxtKey 
and ActiveStatus != 'NonActive' and ElemName = 'xyz' order by TrnDate desc
```

This query gets executed in SSMS in 5 seconds, but while executing via C# code,
It takes around 5+ minutes.

My C# code accepts query case no. in "BuildQuery" prepares above statement and
return a sqlcommand, I pass parameters and execute it, but "sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();" takes much time.

```
private bool MainFunction(parameters)
{
    CheckXMLDate(4,'9/6/2016 1:00:00 PM','ABC','123' );
}

________________________________

public bool CheckXMLDate(bldqry,TrnDate,TxtID,TxtKey )
{
    SqlCommand sqlCommand = BuildQuery(bldqry);

    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TrnDate", TrnDate);
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TxtID", TxtID);
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TxtKey", TxtKey);
    SqlDataReader dataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

    //Some statements like below...
    if (check == success)
   {    dataReader.Close();
        return true;}

    dataReader.Close();
    return false;
}
_______________________________________

public SqlCommand BuildQuery(int caseNum)
{
string QryString = string.Empty;
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(); 
sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
sqlCommand.Connection = con;

switch (caseNum)
{                
case 4: 
        {
            QryString = "select TblXml from MainTbl with (nolock) "+
                        "where TrnDate < @TrnDate "+
                        "and TxtID = @TxtID "+
                        "and TxtKey = @TxtKey " +
                        "and ActiveStatus != 'NonActive' and ElemName = 'xyz' order by TrnDate desc";
            break;
        }
 default:
        { break; }
}
sqlCommand.CommandText = QryString;
sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 800;
return sqlCommand;
}
```

All parameters are of string type here.

Comment: Can you share your c# code

Comment: is the query below a Stored Procedure? then it might be because of parameter sniffing. For more information about parametersniffing: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/ For possible workarounds then: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/turgays/2013/09/10/parameter-sniffing-problem-and-possible-workarounds/

Comment: @Nebi - No, it is a simple select statement

Comment: Without the COMPLETE c# code we will simply be guessing and it would be better to be able to focus on your exact issue rather than that.  Please show ALL of the related c# code - including how the query is built (if inline code show that, show the stored procedure if that is used etc.)

Comment: `sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;` or whatever type you ARE using would be good to add in there. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtype(v=vs.110).aspx -although text IS the default...

Comment: have you verified that the query created and stored in `bldqry` is the same as your test query? And that the same parameter values are definitely being passed in?

Comment: The extra time is normal.  I sometime use sqlcmd.exe which comes with SQL Server which is a command line executable for SQL Server.  It has an option to output in csv format.  So I run sqlcmd.exe using Process() class in c# then read the csv output.  Much faster but requires more code.

Comment: @jdweng I've never seen anything more than a trivial difference in execution times between SSMS and C#. A difference of 5 seconds / 5 minutes for a fairly simple query is "normal" just because the executing environment is different?? No C# applications would ever get written if that was true. I would suggest there is some difference in the final queries being executed which will account for the large variation.

Comment: I've seen differences in huge queries of 45 minutes or longer with SQL Express.  I suspect it was due to the database not being compressed.  Express does have a method for compressing.

Comment: @ADyson - Yes my bldqry function is preparing the exact query which I mentioned above. I have a constraint that I cannot do any modification in this table as it is a production Database.

Comment: @Trupti have you verified it, e.g. using SQL profiler to check the final query, including the values of the parameters? Parameter values not being what you expect them to be could have a big impact. Regarding your constraint, if it does turn out that you need a new index or something, then you'll just have to request to make a change, production system or not. production systems are not set in stone, as long as proper change processes are followed. You could (and should) create a test server and use the same data to test this without impacting on production.

Comment: @Trupti ...doing that would also rule out the DB environment being the issue, rather than the different clients

Comment: As an experiment, try placing the date in this part: `TrnDate < @TrnDate` directly into the SQL, like `TrnDate < '2016-01-01 00:00:00'` and see if this changes things. If it does you'll likely want to add a query hint for this parameter, tuck on this at the end: `OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@TrnDate = '2016-01-01 00:00:00'))` (pick a date that fits your usecase).

Comment: One likely cause we've seen is that the query optimizer is only given parameters, not likely parameter values, when optimizing which means it has no idea if that part of the clause will end up doing a short scan through a few rows or a table-scan, and in some cases picks a table scan.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - Yes, when I replace parameterized query with plain text and directly put values as you shown above, its performance gets improved and starts executing it within microseconds.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - pick a date that fits your usecase - Can I pass same `@TrnDate` in OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@TrnDate = '2016-01-01 00:00:00'))?

Comment: I don't think so, I think it has to be a literal, otherwise what is the point? The whole problem (if this *is* the problem) is that the query optimizer doesn't know which value to optimize for because it hasn't been given the values. If you can write `OPTIMIZE FOR (@TrnDate = @TrnDate)` then clearly it should be given the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below changes at the time of passing parameters have improved the query's performance and it is executing again in seconds.

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@TrnDate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TrnDate;
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@TxtID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TxtID;
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@TxtKey", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TxtKey;
```

Thanks everyone for all the suggestions!

Comment: For additional explanation see [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Answer (score 0):

You dont appear to have any index to optimize the query.  create a multiple-field index on ( ElemName, TxtID, TxtKey, ActiveStatus, TrnDate )

Comment: good suggestion, but, out of interest, why would this account for the difference between the two execution environments? I would have thought an index would have an identical effect no matter how the query is executed. I would suspect that the OP's two queries are not, in fact, identical.

Comment: @ADyson, I agree with you in suspicion of different queries.   Also, I've seen stranger things.